# Is the following true for integers $p_{x\leq y}\iff \lnot p_{y<x}$

Tags: logic, order-theory

$p_{x \leq y}$ is the variable that  is true when a given x is less than or equal to a given y ,false otherwise.

My book says that $p_{x\leq y}\implies \lnot p_{y<x}$ is true for integers but i feel like they could be even equivalent to one another hence $p_{x\leq y}\iff \lnot p_{y<x}$. Am i wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

For any linear order <=, such as the integers,
x <= y iff not (y < x).  The use of P makes no sense.

Comment: While it does seem unmotivated (in the brief context provided by the Question at present), there is nothing nonsensical about defining propositional variables in order to relate/compare truth values.  You'll perhaps want to get [an introduction to posting mathematical expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).